# Loop postgresql Function through Date Range

Tags: postgresql

I have a user defined function. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413203/writing-a-function-in-sql-to-loop-through-a-date-range-in-a-udf) shows how to loop through dates. Using this approach, I tried this query:

```
select myfun(a::date) from generate_series('2015-01-01'::date,'2016-01-27','1 day') s(a)
```

This doesn't quite work. What it returns is a single column of the form:

```
(10101, "Sample",  "test")
(10102, "Sample2", "test2")
```

When in reality there should be three columns. It merges them into one.

I noticed that this is the same behavior that you get in a vanilla query such as `select mytable` when I omit the asterisk. The above query doesn't have an asterisk in it, but adding one causes an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the function call in the `FROM` clause:

```
select f.*
from 
    generate_series('2015-01-01'::date,'2016-01-27','1 day') s(a),
    myfun(a::date) f;
```

or using more formal syntax:

```
select f.*
from generate_series('2015-01-01'::date,'2016-01-27','1 day') s(a)
cross join myfun(a::date) f;
```

This form of the `FROM` clause is known as *lateral join*.